# Ubuntu 22.04 Dell E7440 boot error message not found on log files

Tags: dell, 22.04, ubuntu-core

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my Dell E7440.
A red-colored "FAILED" message appears on booting, and is quickly overwritten. I cannot read the message: the screen quickly changes.
I tried to browse log-files. I cannot identify the error msg.
Any hint?

Comment: Is your computer booting into the installed Ubuntu 22.04 so that you get a working operating system? In that case the message was probably not very important. Otherwise maybe someone who knows log-files better than I can help you.

Comment: Thank you sudodus for you reply. I got a working operating system. However, i also got some "internal error" warnings while working with my system...

Comment: It is important that you specify the warnings in detail. Please repeat booting and read a bit longer each time until you can edit your original question and write what you think it is about. - Maybe you can also recognize the output in one of the following log files in the directory `/var/log/` : `boot.log`, `kern.log` and `syslog`.

Comment: Thank you sudodus for your additional hints. Unfortunately the message QUICKLY disappears. I cannot find it in any log file...

Comment: You have a working operating system. Probably the message is only a warning, and you can live with it, even if it is a little frustrating that you cannot read it. -- But what "internal error" warnings while working with your system are there? That way we might find out about a problem, that should not be ignored.

Comment: You can also run `dmesg|less` to display all messages from the kernel ring buffer.